# Serilog timing library, log to a different sink

Tags: c#, serilog

I'm in the process of converting a small project from log4net to serilog, which so far is going well. However, I need to log performance / timings in a file by itself. There is the timing library that I'm considering. But I just can't get my head around how to make it log to a specific file using the `WriteTo.Logger` and `Filter.ByIncludingOnly`, what kind of filter would solve this ?

My current solution is to create a specific class `LogImportStatistics` with the responsibility to log timings using `StopWatch` for measuring and then make a sublogger with a filter like

```
 new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.AppSettings()
            .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource<LogImportStatistics>())
            .WriteTo.File("statistic.txt")).CreateLogger();
```

the filter is made possible cause my `LogImportStatistics` sets the context `ForContext(typeof(LogImportStatistics))` on the logger and uses that logger
However, I really would like to be able to use serilog timing library instead and write to a specific file.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/nblumhardt/serilog-timings#use-with-ilogger. That way you can have for example a named "TimingLogger" that you can configure separately from the others.

Comment: @Fildor Maybe I don't fully understand it, but as I see it, this will still mix logging to same sink if there are both timing logs and normal logging event though the context is specified for the class ? Or is there something I'm missing ?